# How to centrally distribute Office-JS Word Add-ins in a Office 365 on-premise environment

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

We tried Sideloading, everything works.

When we tried using Sharepoint Catalog, We are getting an error message that says: "this add-in uses features not supported by its add-in catalog"

Any ideas thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to distribute in an O365 on-premise environment is to use the WebAddinSideloader tool. After installation, enter this command

```
Set-WebAddin -install -installPath c:\add-in -manifestPath \\server\share\manifest.xml
```

For details about the tool, see [WeAddinSideloader](https://github.com/davecra/WebAddinSideloader).

Comment: Thank you - is Microsoft not planning on releasing something that enables this? A lot of enterprises are going to be using on-premise environment for the near future.

Also documentation says side-loading should not be used in production environments

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are no plans at the moment to provide a better story for the distribution of Office Add-ins in O365 on-premise.

Comment: I understand, thanks for letting us know. Would it be possible to put something in the public Appstore and limit it to a specific network? Possibly as a workaround?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can check out the documentation for the store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/

Comment: Thanks for this -  would you recommend the same tool to distribute on Word 2016 in an on-premise environment?